# Stack Snippet comments not showing up correctly when part of code

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, markdown-rendering

I'm trying add a "**stack snippet starter pack**" for tag wikis for specific libraries so there's a ready-to-go template when adding a tag that a user (or answerer) could copy and paste into their question.  In particular, this is occurring on the tag for [bootstrap-multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-multiselect)

However, the markdown is rendering odd and eagerly evaluating the snippet syntax even though it's been indented four spaces over as code.

For example, the following code should display a stack snippet that could be pasted into an answer:

#### Here's a live snippet - it should be working, but isn't

```
    $(function() {
        $('.multiselect').multiselect();
    });
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
        <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
        <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
        <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
        <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
        <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    </select>
```

#### Here's the actual code - only got there by escaping manually

```
    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

    <!-- language: lang-js -->

        $(function() {
            $('.multiselect').multiselect();
        });

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

        <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
            <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
            <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
            <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
            <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
            <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
        </select>

    <!-- end snippet -->
```

I know that previews aren't always a faithful reproduction of how it will actually be rendered, but in this case the preview is the best option and Meta and the Tag Wiki's are much worse.

#### Here's a picture representation of the issue:

[image: screenshot]

[Here's a reproduction of this issue in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254289/209031)

Comment: See [Stack Snippets delimiters are being parsed too eagerly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284254/stack-snippets-delimiters-are-being-parsed-too-eagerly)