# What library is used for "special comments" for code blocks

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

At Stack Overflow, we can use [special comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to indicate language of indented code blocks.

I mean, the comments like

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

and

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
```

I know, SO uses Google Prettify, but are these "special comments" a part of Google Prettify, or is it some another library? I've briefly read the docs about Google Prettify. It seems "special comments" are not described in these docs.

I know there are existing questions about "how to use highlighing" and "what tools are used at StackExchange" (like the link Daedalus posted; thanks). But my question is not about "how to use highlighing" and, also, it isn't about "general information about tools used at StackExchange". Instead, it is about a specific feature.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that this is Stack Exchange specific.

Honestly, I don't think you need any libraries to implement this. This is simple enough to solve with regular expressions. What those should look like depends a bit on your language of choice, but here are some starting points that are fairly generic regular expressions.

*Detect all language comments that are on their own line.*
`/^<!--\s+language(?:-all)?:\s+([a-z\-]+)\s+-->$/igm`
This captures the language in a group and detects both `language` and `language-all` comments. Caveat: this regular expression only eats language names with `[A-Za-z]` and `-` characters. Of course, it should be easy to change this if you want.

*Detect all comments with key/value pairs.*
`/^<!--\s+(?:([a-z\-]+):\s+([a-z\-]+)\s+)+-->$/igm`
This captures any comments of the form `<!-- key: value other-key: other-value -->`. This is used for the [Stack Snippets](//stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Keys and values should be captured in groups, but you cannot really [access them all](//stackoverflow.com/q/37003623/962603). Only the last one is stored. Well, as I said, it's a starting point.

**Obligatory warning.** Since MarkDown is a superset of HTML, you are potentially parsing HTML with regular expressions here. That is a [b̼̺̥ͅa̴̫̬̼͇d̳͓͎͢ ̣̬ͅí̱̗̙͍͍̙ͅd̞͖͉̲ͅea̜̱̺͖͎͍](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). It may be better to somehow retrieve comment nodes from your Markdown parser and use (variants of) the above regular expressions on their contents.

Comment: Big thanks, upvoted. I will wait a bit and probably accept it in 2 days.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex? Now you have ţ̣͉̼w̰͇͔̳̱̟͜o̯̼ ̼̞͖̗̻p͖̗̞̱̲̫͡r̠̞̗͕̞̤o̧̭̪̭̭͈̩b̮͇͉̫̦̠ḽ̭͎̻͔e͉m̮̰̤̮̟͙̮s̞͕̩͔͕͇

Comment: @Justastudent you could be; markdown is a superset of HMTL. Also you'd have issues parsing posts just like the OP's, where the language tags are actually in code blocks and not expected to alter the highlighting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284254/stack-snippets-delimiters-are-being-parsed-too-eagerly